# WebAPI CORS - why is the OPTIONS request making its way into my Controller?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, asp.net-web-api2, http-options-method

I have CORS working with the following:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPut]
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("OPTIONS")]
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/exercise")]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateExercise(Exercise exercise) {
    try {
        _adminService.UpdateExercise(exercise);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }
}
```

In my `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest() {
    if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS") {
        Response.Flush();
    }
}
```

But something weird is happening - if I set a breakpoint in my controller, the OPTIONS request makes its way to the innards with a `null` exercise.  Why is this happening?  I would expect the `Flush()` to prevent this.

As it stands, I need to add checks for null to all of my CORS-sensitive endpoints (PUTs, DELETEs).  This seems inelegant... should I be able to prevent OPTIONS requests from hitting the controller logic, instead just responding with the required headers straight-away?

Comment: @CarlHancke - that did the trick.  Looks like I had half of another method implemented... feel free to post as answer, and thanks so much :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding this as an answer, based on the comments in the question.

The problem is caused by accepting the `OPTIONS` verb on the action method. The MVC runtime then tries to execute the action method & the `null` problem occurs.

Remove the verb so MVC doesn't try to execute the method & the `Application_BeginRequest` event will sort out the pre-flight issue for you.