# CORS settings for IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, cors, web-config, iis-7.5

How can I convert the following code for use in the web.config in IIS 7.5 and where in the web.config file I should place each piece of code?

```
# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
 
# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

Comment: As per the recommendation from site - http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html i've added       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> to my web.config. but I get the following message in Firefox - Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://lrpspsprd02.lhl.co.nz/ZFP/Dicom/UrlAuthentication?mode=StandAloneLaunch. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Answer (score 28):

If you are asking this to solve **CORS** problem, you can follow this solution below.

**NOTE:** Before adding all this you should consider security issues.

1. Add this to your web.config file:

   ```
   <system.webServer>
     <httpProtocol>
       <customHeaders>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With, origin, content-type, accept" />
       </customHeaders>
     </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
   ```
2. If you have Content-type
           parameter in your **ajax** call or you are doing PUT request.Those
           are considered as **PreFlight** requests.Preflight requests are doing
           **OPTION** request before sending main request(PUT,DELETE etc).You can
           add below method to your global.asax file to pass successfully OPTION process:

   ```
   protected void Application_BeginRequest()
   {
       if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
       {
           Response.Flush();
       }
   }
   ```

> To have more information about Preflight requests you can check [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)
>
> For solution number 2 you can have detailed information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624386/handling-cors-preflight-requests-to-asp-net-mvc-actions)

Comment: I had to prepend the following lines to <customHeaders> in order to prevent a duplicate entry error: 
<remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
<remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" />
<remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" />
<remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" />

Comment: Thanks to @zehra Subas.For me i just had to add only these two lines headers,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Headers:

       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With, origin, content-type, accept" />

Comment: Welcome :) @SotirisZegiannis

Comment: There's also an IIS CORS module, using the `<cors>` tag, more info can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference

Answer (score 1):

Some updates needs to be considered as Chrome now adds strict-origin-when-cross-origin as default referrer-policy, so if you don't set a referrer policy in the web.config, you might still run into the CORS issue. This is the setting worked for me when testing a localhost test program against a remote server (the settings are not recommended for production):

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
         <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="no-referrer" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With, origin, content-type, accept" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```