# How to handle cross domain request between an asp.net web page and a WCF service hosted in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, iis

I have written a WCF web service which is being hosted in Windows Server 2012 through IIS-7.  The server's public IP is currently open (the firewall is disabled).  I can get the metadata and the wsdl document just fine with a browser, and I can add the service reference to Visual Studio through that IP.  However, when my asp.net web page invokes a WCF service method,  it gives me a 405 - Method Not Allowed error.

I think the problem is with cross-domain posting.  I could be wrong, but that would make sense, since I only get errors when accessing the wcf service from an application.

How would I go about avoiding this issue?

Here is my Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataPortalWCFService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string HelloWorldTest(string u, string p);

    [OperationContract]
    string HelloWorldTest2(string u, string p, string str);

    [OperationContract]
    string HelloWorldTest3(string u, string p);

    [OperationContract]
    DataTable GetBAQResults(string u, string p, string BAQName, DataTable BAQParameters);

    [OperationContract]
    string GetBAQResultsAsJSON(string u, string p, string BAQName, string BAQParameters);

}
```

Comment: How does the service contract for your WCF service look like, for instance the method being invoked?

Comment: I edited the OP

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with cross domain headers when hosting a WCF service in IIS should be essentially the same as any other type of web site being hosted in IIS. The following question should help you find a solution...

[CORS settings for IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488535/cors-settings-for-iis-7-5)

Another way of solving this issue would be to simply reuse the domain.

e.g. for your web site use:-

www.mygreat.com

and for your api use

api.mygreat.com