# jQuery + ASP.NET Web API + CORS error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a simple ASP.NET Web API application with individual accounts for authentication.

I enabled CORS in it: installed package and added:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
        origins: "*",
        headers: "*",
        methods: "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

to the file **WebApiConfig**.

Now, I want to make requests from a simple web page using jQuery. I have this code now:

```
var loginData = {
    grant_type: "password",
    username: "foo",
    password: "Something_1562"
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "https://localhost:44351/Token",
    data: loginData
}).done(function (data) {
    alert(data.userName);
    alert(data.access_token);

}).fail(function (data) {
    alert('Request Status: ' + req.status + ' Status Text: ' + req.statusText + ' ' + req.responseText);
});
```

And I get this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:44351/Token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

EDIT:

Some extra information:
 - I have https/ssl enable on the web api
 - The API is running on ISS Express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope these following couple of points & links are useful:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

The value of `"*"` is special in that it does not allow requests to supply credentials, meaning HTTP authentication, client-side SSL certificates, nor does it allow cookies to be sent. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Simple_example)

Therefore your Web API needs to specify which URL is accessing it using AJAX. For example.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://yourAjaxClientURL", headers: "*", 
    methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
```

To allow cross-origin credentials in Web API, set the `SupportsCredentials` property to `true` on the `[EnableCors]` attribute. Source: [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#credentials)

Third useful link [www.w3.org - cors](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests)

Comment: Btw, I'm now having a different problem: my GET requests are being changed to OPTIONS which results on a 405 code. I have read some posts but nothing works... Any tips?

Comment: @CátiaAzevedo Also maybe these links are helpful too: http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488535/cors-settings-for-iis-7-5

Comment: @CátiaAzevedo if the new problem exists, then it might worthwhile to create a new question. I'm not familiar with the "GET requests are being changed to OPTIONS" message - sorry