# CORS - Delete and Put are not working,

Tags: cors, iis-7.5, put, http-delete, webapi2

[image]

I did all the setting,

1. Standerd web api config
2. Added all origins
3. AllowAnyMethod,AllowAnyHeader,SupportsCredentials,AllowAnyOrigin set to true
4. From IIS 7.5  delegation , set values to Read/Write

but still not able to make Delete and Put APIs.

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your response doesn't contain any CROS `Access-Control` headers. Also, to work with DELETE and PUT method requests you should respond properly to the preflight OPTIONS request.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30222670/630372) for a simple (though slightly unsafe) solution.