# CORS is enabled but still get 405

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm writing a quick and dirty little script to log traffic on a static HTML page. I am making a POST to another server where I have the API hosted. The server has CORS enabled (see code below) but I still get a 405.

```xml
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```js
  var host = window.location.host;
  var hostname = window.location.hostname;
  var href = window.location.href;
  var port = window.location.port;
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  var referrer = document.referrer;

  var obj = { 
    Host: host,
    HostName: hostname,
    Href: href,
    Port: port,
    Path: path,
    Referrer: referrer
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/system/api/sp/logvisit',
    data: obj,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json'
  });
```

Here is my controller:

```c#
namespace Gs.Api
{
    public class SPController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("api/sp/logvisit")]
        [HttpPost]
        public void LogVisit(LogVisitRequest request)
        {
            // do stuff with request
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the main answer here [Handling CORS Preflight requests to ASP.NET MVC actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624386/handling-cors-preflight-requests-to-asp-net-mvc-actions/13646169#13646169) which got rid of the 405 but my method never actually got called. I tried several other fixes from various answers here and some got rid of the error but my posted object would be null.

Comment: Verify that you  can call the method from the same origin.

Comment: @11thdimension Method works fine using ARC (Advanced REST Client - from Chrome App Store)

Comment: REST clients are not bound by the CORS, try with Ajax.

Comment: @11thdimension it got a 500 error but I changed to JSON.stringify(obj) and it worked from my local. If I add [HttpOptions] to the call it gets a 500 error because request is null.

Comment: @11thdimension I figured it out. Posting answer soon once I type it all up. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out on my own. I had to take a few other solutions and use them all together, but I got it finally.

1. I used this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13646169/3920075
2. I changed `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />` to `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />`.
3. I changed `data: obj`, to `data: JSON.stringify(obj)`