# post request odata with cors

Tags: c#, cors, odata, angularjs-http

Im writing a little service using c#(.net framework) and odata V4. My clientside is AngularJs.
On my localhost everythink works fine, but when Im releasing my code to the server(widows server 2012 R2) I got cors problems.
I tried different solutions:

1. Tried to put `Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` at web.config, got `401` and `500` response preflight.
2. add `CorsHandler` class to handle the preflight/add `Application_BeginRequest` to handle it as well, no luck (return there the Access-Control-Allow-Origin and etc...). and stuff from here as well:
   [Handling CORS Preflight requests to ASP.NET MVC actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624386/handling-cors-preflight-requests-to-asp-net-mvc-actions)

and finally tried the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package just like that:

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("cool.mydomain", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
```

And guess what, its no helping either!

When I send the `POST` method I have to send it with `Content-Type:"x-www-form-urlencoded"`, because `application/json` triggers the preflight, and `text/plain` is not supported for some reason.I have an enpoint which use `ODataActionParameters` object, and its always null,assuming because of the content type of the urlencoded.

Hope Someone can help me, Im banging my head...

Comment: contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' normally works for me.

Comment: forgot to mention that im using angularjs, so the defult of $http post method header is that content type. i updated my question

Comment: Try [this slightly different solution](https://forums.asp.net/t/2032931.aspx?How+to+enable+CORS+in+Odata+NET+service+) in your `Application_BeginRequest` method. It addresses explicitly `odata` requests. Also, check [this detailed info about CORS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0):

After examining again Diana's link, I made it work. But I made changes. I return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` for every request, and if its `OPTIONS` request, I return the rest of the headers:

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest()
            {
                Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ORIGINS);
                Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
                if (Context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
                {                    
                    Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
                    Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");                    
                    Context.Response.End();
                }
            }
```